# Sharepoint 2010 BDC not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, status, business-data-catalog

I want to create external content type, so in central admin I create a new Business Data Connectivity Service (BDC) 
and I start the service from system settings --> manage service on servers. but when I get back to application management  --> Manage Service application the status is stopped. I made an IISReset, with no luck, when I click on my (BDC), I have the following error :

```
The load balancer is not provisioned. Verify the load balancer was provisioned successfully before retrieving endpoint addresses.
```

I tried 3 times to re-create the BDC. but still not working.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do the following :

- login with SharePoint Farm Account.
- Make Sure that the SharePoint Timer Service is Running, also try to restart it
- Make Sure that the BDC Service account has been added to Managed Account in Central Administration.
- Remove the BDC service from Manage Application Service in Central Administration.
- Restart IIS.
- Restart BDC service at  `manage service on servers` then reconfigures it again.
- Restart IIS.
- After it has been created and started > Make Sure that the BDC Application Service is connected to the Web Application.

If all the above steps do not help , try to install [SharePoint 2010 SP2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39672)  then run Sharepoint Configuration Wizard , then try to create BDC again that should be now created and started successfully . (**Note** : It's heavily recommended to install SharePoint Service Pack first at dev environment , also take a backup to allow rollback.)

**Note :** Some [articles](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f60259f6-72db-461c-940b-7d81ccf1b50d/business-data-connectivity-the-load-balancer-is-not-provisioned?forum=sharepointadminprevious) said to try to install [WCF hotfix for .Net FrameWork 3.5 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976462)  but really I can't find any link for this hotfix.